# Favor to someone vs. favor for someone

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What's the correct option? maybe both are correct?

Example sentence:

> It's not a favor for/to me, but for/to you.

I found both on the net:

> "Actually, not a favor for me but for Libby." [Source](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=KhZhBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT335&lpg=PT335&dq=%22not%20a%20favor%20for%20me%20but%22&source=bl&ots=K-Z-outcqD&sig=ACfU3U0EzBEK9MmxcTvDyzPzuQGiXP26OA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjipYPknNTpAhULBZQKHSA0A6YQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22not%20a%20favor%20for%20me%20but%22&f=false).
>
> Not a favor to me but to your own self. [Source](https://www.pinterest.com/fiebrucustoms/motivational/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google ngram search shows both occur, with "a favor to" being more frequent. (However, looking at the examples of actual uses that can be accessed at the bottom of the screen shows that some of them are actually different usages, so use the results with care.)

[Google ngram "a favor to, a favor for"](https://tinyurl.com/y7yrka5q)

With the phrase "do a favor", you have to use "for", because "do a favor to" sounds almost like a joke, parallel to "do harm to".

But it's common to say "do X as a favor to Y'; there the receiver isn't the indirect object of "do", but the beneficiary of the favor.