# A favor to me vs. a favor for me

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the correct alternative and why?

Example sentence:

> This isn't a favor to/for me---but to/for you. (Meaning that the one benefited is the other person, not the speaker.)

Comment: We usually speak of doing a favour _to_ someone. Why? Because that's what we say!

Comment: Him.... Maybe this is a difference between the UK and US? Because I am not familiar with people using "to" instead of "for" here. Merriam Webster also only gives "used as a function word to indicate the object or recipient of a perception, desire, or activity," in the definition of "for".

Comment: Never mind, embefær has capture the distinction between the two. One is from one to the other, and the other is just a remark about something that happened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Favor to someone vs. favor for someone](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/248743/favor-to-someone-vs-favor-for-someone)

Comment: I've just noticed that @alexchenco has already asked this question!!

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry, I forgot about it!

Answer (score 2):

To firstly answer your question, the sentence should be as follows:

> This isn't a favour for me, but a favour for you.

If you use the alternative:

> This isn't a favour to me, but a favour to you.

The person delivering the favour is ambiguous; it could be the speaker or it could be a third party.

If you wish the person deliering the favour to be unambiguously the speaker, you should opt for the first example.

The reason being that the preposition '[*for*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/for)' is explicitly about the receipt of one thing from a given source and, given the other meanings of for, also has a weight of there being a reasoning behind this. As you have already contrasted the pronoun '*me*', it would strongly imply the source is also the speaker.

Conversely, the preposition '[*to*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/to)' simply implies a direction of exchange from source to target and hence the person delivering the favour is ambiguous.

I should say, even the first example could be made ambiguous but I think would not normatively be considered so.

Answer (score 1):

"This isn't a favor for me but for you." is the correct version.

While both "for" and "to" can be "used as a function word to indicate purpose, intention, tendency, result, or end" (Merriam Webster), "for" can also be "used as a function word to indicate the object or recipient of a perception, desire, or activity," while "to" cannot.